# hashing with chaining c code

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, hash

Here is the hashing with chaining code.  I am having some pointer doubts here

```
struct hash* hashTable = NULL;
int          eleCount  = 0;

struct node
{
    int          key;
    int          age;
    char         name[100];
    struct node* next;
};

struct hash
{
    struct node* head;
    int          count;
};

struct node* createNode(int key, char *name, int age)
{
    struct node* newnode;

    newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newnode->key = key;
    newnode->age = age;
    strcpy(newnode->name, name);
    newnode->next = NULL;

    return newnode;
}

void insertToHash(int key, char *name, int age)
{
    int          hashIndex = key % eleCount;
    struct node* newnode   = createNode(key, name, age);

    /* head of list for the bucket with index "hashIndex" */
    if (!hashTable[hashIndex].head)
    {
        hashTable[hashIndex].head  = newnode;
        hashTable[hashIndex].count = 1;

        return;
    }

    /* adding new node to the list */
    newnode->next = (hashTable[hashIndex].head);
    /*
     * update the head of the list and no of
     * nodes in the current bucket
     */
    hashTable[hashIndex].head = newnode;
    hashTable[hashIndex].count++;
    return;
}
```

How has `hashTable` turned into an array it was a pointer to hash right??
And, what actually is

```
struct hash
{
    struct node* head;
    int          count;
};
```

I'm not getting how this structure is actually working??
Can we convert any pointer to a structure as an array???

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what you're asking about. Please try to clarify.

Comment: it is a hash table with chaining it is same kind of a data structure as of adjacency list in graphs..am not able to understand how struct hash *hashTable is used as an array inside inserttohash function

Comment: Pointers and arrays behave very similarly in C. You can use `[]` with both.

Comment: This implementation of hashtable is not correct, we cannot get O(1) retrieval time (even when there are no collisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hashTable` is indeed a pointer to a structure.  But, somewhere in the code (which you don't show) memory is allocated for an array of `struct hash`.  The address of this memory is then assigned to `hashTable`.  Then when you do `hashTable[index];` you're simply accessing this allocated array.

In C, when you write `hashTable[index];` this is identical to `*(hashTable + index)`.  Then, adding `index` to this pointer result in an address that is `index * sizeof(struct hash)` further.  This has the effect of 'jumping' to the `index`' element in the array.

For more details read the [appropriate section in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).